# Chassis ground for DC power supply

Tags: dc, ground

Car jumpstarting is usually done according to this diagram: [image]

What is the point of attaching the negative terminal of the donor to chassis ground instead of the negative terminal? How would that work anyway? To my knowledge you can't use Earth or Chassis ground as a replacement for DC negative terminals.

Comment: [Not every car has a negative chassis.](https://www.restore-an-old-car.com/positive-ground-cars.html) And back in the day we often jump started our car (many times me included) by rolling it down an incline and popping the clutch to engage gearing when the speed was right. I still much prefer manual shift to this day. But the point is I still check chassis to be sure it is negative. Old habit, but good habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the point of attaching the negative terminal of the donor to chassis ground instead of the negative terminal?

Safety. By connecting the negative terminal of the donor to the chassis of the receiver, AND BY MAKING THAT CONNECTION LAST, and breaking that connection first, one avoids sparks near the battery.

Also, as Finbarr points out in a comment below, if you connect the negative cable first, you run the risk of accidentally touching the positive cable to chassis, causing a short.

> To my knowledge you can't use Earth or Chassis ground as a replacement for DC negative terminals.

The negative terminal of the battery is connected to the vehicle's chassis. Electrically, except for a very small resistance, a connection to the chassis is electrically equivalent to a connection to the negative terminal of the battery.

Comment: The other reason is that if you connect the negative lead first, you run the risk of touching the chassis and causing a short while connecting the positive lead.

Comment: I'm not sure you've answered the question. The original question is not in what order to connect the cables and Why. I understand the question as follows: Why are the cables connected directly to the battery on one side and not on the other?

Comment: @Vincent. The reason is safety. But connecting the negative to chassis only provides safety if the positive is connected first.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy, I'm sorry, I didn't see your sentence "one avoids sparks near the battery."

Answer (score 1):

Those instruction assume the vehicle is negative chassis i.e. the negative of the battery is electrically bonded to chassis. This is true for the majority of (maybe all) modern vehicles. Historically this was not the case and positive chassis was more common.

Lead acid batteries produce hydrogen & oxygen gas when charging. The idea behind  attaching the negative lead to chassis is it is further away from the battery and lowers the risk of fire/explosion resulting from the sparking when making or breaking the circuit.